# Determining average RGB values of raster layer image inside selected polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, image, rgb

I have a layer which contains a number of polygons(around 10,000). My work is to check the imagery layer colour inside of that polygon and write a colour in the 'Ceiling_ID' field based on its average rgb values.

I need to populate rgb values only on few selected polygons.

How can I achieve this?

I do have a license for ArcInfo, but not able to run zonal statistics.

Imagery layer is an online wms service.

[image: This]

This attached image can explain my problem a little bit more clearly.

Here I have selected a polygon and by analyzing its image I have to give its 'Ceiling_ID' field a value based on its roof colour. Which is light grey in this example.

Comment: No coding needed. Run zonal statistics on individual raster bands.

Comment: @FelixIP I will try to use your solution if it works.

Comment: It must work, because it can't fail unless your polygons overlap.

Comment: @FelixIP Unfortunately, It says that I have to purchase a license to use this feature. Is there any other workaround to this.

Comment: If you do not have access to a Spatial Analyst license then that is a detail that you should [edit] into your question.

Comment: I have installed the Arcinfo license but still I am not able to run this tool.